# Tableau Remove extra space within sheet border

Tags: whitespace, tableau-api, gridlines

I am creating sheet with rows of Sale Sums and Columns of each month. Firstly, I am trying to remove this extra whitespace within the boundaries while keeping the squares the same size. I would like the squares of data to take up the entirety of the region. Also, I have tried creating lines to separate each row but adding grid lines creates lines going through the squares.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to format > borders
[image]

select none in columns

[image]

select none in rows

[image]